# Python: How I can do a double parse in a list with a filter in the middle?

Tags: python, parsing

I have a string like this in python:

```
</info>;ct=0;if="sensor";obs;rt="urn:oma:lwm2m:oma:1",</time>;ct=0;if="sensor";rt="urn:oma:lwm2m:ext:3333",...
```

The objective is to have and print a list of the resources that contains "obs" like this: [/info, ...] the problem is that "obs" does not have to be in the same position.

At first I did a parse by (,) and with a loop for creates a list, then I want to filter by "obs" and finally parse again by ";" and remove the "<>" of the resources.

I started with this code but I am not sure how I should continue.

```
string = </info>;ct=0;if="sensor";obs;rt="urn:oma:lwm2m:oma:1",</time>;ct=0;if="sensor";rt="urn:oma:lwm2m:ext:3333",...

list = string.split(',')


for n in list:
  if ";obs;" in list:
     continue
  print(n) # for check it
```

...

It doesn't work. Python can't find the "obs" in the object list. What is the problem? Can someone help me?

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking to see if `";obs;"` is in `n`?  And aren't you *rejecting* parts that contain `obs`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `if ";obs;" in n` in order to filter for that. Please have a look at this quick example:

```
string = '</info>;ct=0;if="sensor";obs;rt="urn:oma:lwm2m:oma:1",</time>;ct=0;if="sensor";rt="urn:oma:lwm2m:ext:3333",...'
list = string.split(',')

for n in list:
  if ";obs;" in n:
      print(n)
```

I hope that helps!